# What Should Be include in webservide base iPhone App Architecture?

Tags: iphone, xcode, architecture

I have been working with iPhone app as developer and now my PM(Project Manager) wants to make architecture for web-service base app.I have developed Simple Architecture for this app but i don't know it's ok or not.What should i include in iPhone web service base architecture?[image: Web service base app architecture]

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Keep security in mind (encryption, authentication, authorization)!

Comment: @Homes:Can u Provide Simple Demo Image?It will help me lot's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what you app is supposed to do.

I would add documentation of the full HTTP API you are planning to use:

1. Resources
2. Commands supported on those resources
3. Explanation on the purpose of each resource

Basically a full documentation of all the possibilities available in your server for your iOS client to consume.

Comment: Can you Provide Simple Demo architecure?It will help me lot's